# How to create a VHDL function/procedure that can return true or false based on value of signals outside it?

Tags: fpga, vhdl

Here is the function I am trying to write:

```
procedure ASCERTAIN_CALL_VALIDITY is
begin
  (SESSION_CHECK_ACTIVATION_MSG_IN and ACTIVATION_MSG_RECEIVED_INT) or
  (SESSION_CHECK_ACTIVATION_ACKNOWLEDGE_MSG_IN and ACTIVATION_ACKNOWLEDGE_MSG_RECEIVED_INT) or
  (SESSION_CHECK_START_SESSION_MSG_IN and START_SESSION_MSG_RECEIVED_INT) or
  (SESSION_CHECK_STARTUP_CONFIGURATION_MSG_IN and STARTUP_CONFIGURATION_MSG_RECEIVED_INT) or
  (SESSION_CHECK_TURN_OFF_MSG_IN and TURN_OFF_MSG_RECEIVED_INT)
end procedure;
```

I want to return the value from logic processing and store inside a signal or variable outside it. Now the problem is that, functions can't access signals outside of them. Procedures can't return a value. So what do I do now?

Comment: Functions can access signals (in scope at the point of the fn declaration) ; it just makes them impure. So, `impure function ASCERTAIN return BOOLEAN is ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either return a value from the procedure call (which is a statement) or use an impure function:

```vhdl
entity q231 is
end entity;

architecture foo of q231 is
    signal SESSION_CHECK_ACTIVATION_MSG_IN: boolean;
    signal ACTIVATION_MSG_RECEIVED_INT: boolean;
    signal SESSION_CHECK_ACTIVATION_ACKNOWLEDGE_MSG_IN: boolean;
    signal ACTIVATION_ACKNOWLEDGE_MSG_RECEIVED_INT: boolean;
    signal SESSION_CHECK_START_SESSION_MSG_IN: boolean;
    signal START_SESSION_MSG_RECEIVED_INT: boolean;
    signal SESSION_CHECK_STARTUP_CONFIGURATION_MSG_IN: boolean;
    signal STARTUP_CONFIGURATION_MSG_RECEIVED_INT: boolean;
    signal SESSION_CHECK_TURN_OFF_MSG_IN: boolean;
    signal TURN_OFF_MSG_RECEIVED_INT: boolean;
    
    procedure ASCERTAIN_CALL_VALIDITY (result: out boolean) is  -- ADDED out parameter
    begin
        result :=   -- ADDED
      (SESSION_CHECK_ACTIVATION_MSG_IN and ACTIVATION_MSG_RECEIVED_INT) or
      (SESSION_CHECK_ACTIVATION_ACKNOWLEDGE_MSG_IN and ACTIVATION_ACKNOWLEDGE_MSG_RECEIVED_INT) or
      (SESSION_CHECK_START_SESSION_MSG_IN and START_SESSION_MSG_RECEIVED_INT) or
      (SESSION_CHECK_STARTUP_CONFIGURATION_MSG_IN and STARTUP_CONFIGURATION_MSG_RECEIVED_INT) or
      (SESSION_CHECK_TURN_OFF_MSG_IN and TURN_OFF_MSG_RECEIVED_INT) ; -- ADDED ;
    end procedure;
    
    impure function call_validity return boolean is
    begin
        return (SESSION_CHECK_ACTIVATION_MSG_IN and ACTIVATION_MSG_RECEIVED_INT) or
      (SESSION_CHECK_ACTIVATION_ACKNOWLEDGE_MSG_IN and ACTIVATION_ACKNOWLEDGE_MSG_RECEIVED_INT) or
      (SESSION_CHECK_START_SESSION_MSG_IN and START_SESSION_MSG_RECEIVED_INT) or
      (SESSION_CHECK_STARTUP_CONFIGURATION_MSG_IN and STARTUP_CONFIGURATION_MSG_RECEIVED_INT) or
      (SESSION_CHECK_TURN_OFF_MSG_IN and TURN_OFF_MSG_RECEIVED_INT) ;
    end function;
begin
    process
        variable result:    boolean;
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        ASCERTAIN_CALL_VALIDITY(result);
        if not result then
            report "result is not TRUE";
        end if;
        if not call_validity then
            report "call_validity is FALSE";
        end if;
        wait;
    end process;
    
end architecture;
```

Comment: I thought that impure functions can't be synthesized at all?

Comment: Perhaps you could constrain your question further. There are no prohibitions against synthesizing impure functions found in IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (RTL Synthesis, withdrawn). Any such prohibition would be dependent on a  particular synthesis vendor. A lot of places impure functions are used are otherwise ineligible for synthesis (e.g. methods of protected types).

Comment: what tools have you used impure functions in, have you used them with Intel/Altera, Xilinx and Microsemi synthesis tools?

Comment: Xilinx synthesis for example has no problem with impure functions of this sort. A reference for an assertion to the contrary might be enlightening. The requirement to label impure functions is meant to be informative to the reader.

Comment: (additionally `impure` can be read by the compiler as `don't perform certain sorts of optimisations on this function`)